# Eclipse debug output file with timestamp

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, console

Is it possible in Eclipse debugging/running a Java application to direct standard output to a file that has a generated timestamp in the name ?

Currently, I send the output to a text file (ex. server.log), then it either gets overwritten or appended (if i have the checkbox set).  However, I would like to know if there's a way to include a timestamp in the configuration so that the log files are created each time with a generated name with current time in milliseconds ... e.g. server_1346105152004.log ??  I'd like to keep each log, and every time I restart create a new log with a different name.

Has anyone done this ?

Please note: I'm not looking for a logging framework that accomplishes this task, I'm currently using multiple frameworks on different applications that accomplish this.  I'm simply wondering if this is possible within the Eclipse Run/Debug menus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=384844 was fixed now. Now eclipse console output can be redirected to a file with time stamp in it using eclipse **${current_date}** variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is what most of the Java logging frameworks do for you. The idea of using standard out for logging is quite archaic. My personal favorite logging framework is [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/), but [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j) and [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) are also popular.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this, I'm using the slf4j and log4j frameworks in the applications that I'm working on.  I'm simply wondering if there is an easy way to accomplish the same principle in eclipse run/debug menus.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. All you need to do is create a timestamp and the check it when you begin to log it. If one log is later than the other, then create new file, else overwrite.